# Does Wide Guard protect against Dragon Darts?

Tags: pokemon-sword-shield

I was looking to try out double battles online, and from my short experience it seems that Dragapult is a major player in most teams in Sword and Shield.
Dragapult has a unique move called [Dragon Darts](https://www.serebii.net/attackdex-swsh/dragondarts.shtml), which seems to work in a unique way:

> The user attacks twice using Dreepy. If there are two targets, this move hits each target once.

Serebii also states:

> In Doubles, if one of the two opponents protects or is a Fairy-type Pokemon, it hits the opponent that doesn't protect twice.

One strategy I thought about using was the move [Wide Guard](https://www.serebii.net/attackdex-swsh/wideguard.shtml), it is a move that protects from area moves such as Surf, Rock Slide, or anything that hits multiple Pokemon.  The move states:

> The user and its allies are protected from wide-ranging attacks for one turn.

I was wondering, does Dragon Darts count as a "wide-ranging attack"?
Sometimes it only targets one Pokemon, another time it hits both...
Will it get blocked by Wide Guard?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [this](https://www.smogon.com/forums/threads/sword-shield-battle-mechanics-research.3655528/) Smogon Sword/Shield Battle Mechanics research thread,
it has been confirmed that Wide Guard does ***not*** protect against Dragon Darts.

Here is a video on Youtube that shows an online battle where Dragon Darts hits the enemy while Wide Guard was up:

Comment: So it's not a Wide Ranging attack, it's a Multi-attack that can change targets halfway through - like Double Kick instead of Surf